# Calling python functions in R

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I have a Python file that is part of my R project currently, named functions.py. Now I have a series of functions defined in that I would like to call. How would I pass arguments into Python when calling it from R?

It seems that if I use `system('python functions.py hello world')` it will call the file with arguments `hello` and `world`, but how do I then call a specific function while including further arguments?

Comment: consider using the `reticulate` package to run python in R

Comment: Any suggestions on how to use it? *eye roll*

Comment: there are many sites made just to teach you reticulate start [here](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/)

Comment: I've already gone through that, it wasn't helpful. All I gathered from that was how to use it to run entire files(without any arguments) from Python in R.

Comment: are you working in rmarkdown or in rscript?

Comment: RScript, and using the shiny library

Comment: Create a python file that contains the function call with the arguments and then run it as shown in the link

Comment: Or simply use `source_python` and now your functions are available in R. Run them as though you are running R function

Comment: I already said that I've look through the link, and I didn't see anywhere in there about how to pass arguments.

Comment: Check where they used `source_python`

Comment: ```Error in file.exists(file) : object 'functions.py' not found```
Is there a way to specify to look in the same directory that the R file is contained? I'd like this to be as easy to deploy as possible.

Comment: either give the path eg `source_python('~/path/to/file/functions.py')` if you are using windows the something like `source_python('C:/Desktop/functions.py')` etc. Or simply copy the functions.py file and paste it in the working directory folder in R

Comment: Ok, I've got the important pieces moving. Thanks, just gotta wrestle with Shiny now.

Comment: Consider accepting one of the below solutions to close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can use `reticulate` with arguments:

your python file called `greeting.py`

```
def greetings(name,time):
    print(f'Good {time.lower()} {name.upper()}')
```

Now source that into R:

```
reticulate::source_python('greeting.py')
```

Now run it just the normal way you would run a R function:

```
greetings('Biden','evening')
Good evening BIDEN
```